# Typesense 'OR' query mode

Tags: typesense

### Description

I have a case where I'd like to search for multiple query tokens in a single collection like:

```
let searchRequests = {
  'searches': [
    {
      'collection': 'products',
      'q': 'shoe hat dress perfume',
    }
  ]
}
```

each token contains results if I query them individually and also if I query two tokens like so:  `'q': 'shoe hat',`.

**Is there a way to allow for more than two query items?**

### Expected Behavior

I expect to have results returned based on my query tokens `'shoe hat dress perfume',` or in other words an `OR` query mode:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "facet_counts": [],
      "found": 100,
      "hits": [  
        ...
    } 
  ]
}
```

### Actual Behavior

The actual behavior is that nothing is found:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "facet_counts": [],
      "found": 0,
      "hits": [  
        ...
    } 
  ]
}
```

### Metadata

**Typesense Version**: 0.22.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Typesense doesn't support strict ORs](https://github.com/typesense/typesense/issues/532#issuecomment-1046483179) and currently have no plan to do so.

To solve my problem I used `filter_by` instead like so:

```
let searchRequests = {
  'searches': [
    {
      'collection': 'products',
      'q': '*',
      'filter_by': "category:["shoe", "hat", "dress", "perfume"]"
    }
  ]
}
```

This would return all products of category shoe/hat/dress/parfume.

More details on usage of `filter_by` here: https://typesense.org/docs/0.19.0/api/documents.html#index-a-document

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use embedding and then sending
"show hat dress perfume" in the `q` query.

Comment: Please explain the effect of what you propose and explain how it solves the problem.